# Django ORM get respective choices value instead of field value

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

In Django ORM, is there any way that you can directly get the respective choices value instead of the field value in the resulting Queryset.
**Example:**

```
port = models.CharField(
  max_length=5,
  choices=( ('21', 'FTP'), ('22', 'SSH'), (...), .. )
)
```

After the ORM Querying, I need the port name (not the number) in the Queryset itself.

Query:

```
> myModel.objects.filter(...).values()
```

output:

```
> [{"id": 1, "port": "21"}, {"id": 2, "port": "22"}, {...}, ...]
```

What i want:

```
> [{"id": 1, "port": "FTP"}, {"id": 2, "port": "SSH"}, {...}, ...]
```

Comment: Can you please post the FULL query you are trying to make and then specify the expected result and also the result that you are getting. It will also help if you show the FULL model. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `values()` here? Get the myModel objects and call `get_port_display()` on each one.

Comment: I am aware of that, I can easily get the object and loop over it or pass it through a function. But my question is that I need the choice mappings in the result queryset itself, whether with `values()` or without. I just need the queryset to have my choices mappings instead of the stored field value.

Comment: since the display values are not stored in db and get_<field>_display() is an instance function, the only option i can think is annotate a label and assign the choice display value in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

As @neverwalkaloner pointed out, you don't save "FTP" and etc. in your database and thus can't retrieve them with your query set. What you can do is something like this:

```
[{'id': obj.pk, 'port': obj.get_port_display()} for obj in myModel.objects.filter(...)]
```

this will give you:

```
[{"id": 1, "port": "FTP"}, {"id": 2, "port": "SSH"}, {...}, ...]
```

Hope it helps.